# Using Xming to display idle locally

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use Xming and puTTY to display idle from a remote system to my local system. When I try to open idle2.7 and 3.6 I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
main()
File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 1485, in main
root = Tk(className="Idle")
File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__

self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:0.0"
```

I have tried using display 0, 0.0, and localhost:0.0. I have made sure that Xming is active on my local machine and I have set puTTY to allow x11 forwarding. I can't find any more information what else could be the problem. Also I don't have root access on the remote machine so I can't reinstall idle. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: If `X11 forwarding` is enabled, normally the `DISPLAY` environment is set automatically when you connect the remote host via `SSH`.  You don't need to change it yourself.  You  can try [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), it is a SSH client with X-Server built-in.

Comment: Also `X11Forwarding` should be enabled in the remote host SSH server configuration.